# What are the extents that you can use C++ pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, local

Can you use a C++ pointer to reference information in another file? I am seeing if you can reference pieces of information from a local csv file, or should i be using a different language? Added question, would there be a way to run multiple processes at the same time.

Comment: _"Can you use a C++ pointer to reference information in another file?"_ No, that's not possible.

Comment: Any decent book, tutorial or class about C++ should have information about how to read files. It doesn't really matter what the data in the file might be, as long as you can parse the data into in-memory structures. Pointers are unrelated to the issue.

Comment: In general, storing pointers in a file is discouraged.  The operating system may load your program in a different area and the pointer read from the file is outside your program's new area.  You can store file offsets into files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer to point to "memory". Which in case of a typical C++ implementation within a modern operating system means "virtual memory". File storage is not in virtual memory. Operating systems do have ways to "map" files into memory. If you do that, then you can use a pointer to point to virtual memory that is mapped to a file. There is no standard way to map files to memory in C++.

Aside from memory mapping, you can instead create an array - in memory, which you can point to - and read the content of the file into that array. There are standard ways to read content of files.

> would there be a way to run multiple processes at the same time.

Possibly. Modern operating systems support multi-processing.

Comment: Are you sure this question fits on SO (and thus worth answering)? To me 160k+ rep indicates a high level of familiarity with SO.

Comment: @iBug Yes. I believe that understading what "memory" means is essential to programmers, and SO is a good place to find such information.

Answer (score -1):

As explained aside, a pointer contains a memory address, which means that it will point only something that is already into memory, whether this comes from a file or another. You'll need to load it first.

However, if your question is: "can I point onto something that is declared in another **source** file", the answer is "yes". You want to take a look at the `extern` statement, which indicates that we will refer to something that will be compiled apart, then linked altogether a link time, just after compilation. And this is worth for C language, too.

Be aware that `extern` actually applies to the resource itself, not the pointer that will reference it, unless your pointer itself (as a variable) is declared outside.